# Swift won't let me rename custom class to match my controllers?

Tags: swift

Every time I try to do so, it undoes my typing.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set the custom class for a view (`UIView`), not the controller (`UIViewController`). You need to select the "View Controller" on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the `View Controller` to assign the custom class to any view controller.
[image]

Don't forget to set the `Storyboard ID` the same as the class name.
[image]